# Web clip widget in Notification Center

Tags: safari, macos, notifications, dashboard

With the old Dashboard it's possible to create a web clip widget from Safari.
As it seems like the Dashboard is getting phased out and the Notification Center is definitely a handy place to have widgets, is there any way to get this on macOS Sierra?

I can't seem to find an option for this in Safari and also cannot seem to find anything in the app store. 
Does anyone know if there is a way to get web clip widgets in the Notification panel?

Comment: What do you want the webclip to do eventually? If you want to display the latest news stories you can do so with other widgets.

Comment: @oa- I need to display some stats from a cloud based app. Unfortuantely the cloud based app does not have any native apps or widgets for macOS so the only solution that I can see is to have Web Clip widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app can do the same for the new Notifications Center:

https://apps.apple.com/cz/app/glimpse-2/id1524217845?l=cs